# What is faster between find() and Attribute Equals Selector

Tags: jquery

I was writing some code and I was wondering which one was the fastest to find an element and then to add a particular class. Let's say I have this line of code, using method find() :

```
$('#activated_blocs ul').find("[data-id='"+bloc_id+"']").addClass('test');
```

In the other hand, I am looking for the same element but with the attribute equals selector :

```
$('#activated_blocs ul .small-row[data-id="'+bloc_id+'"]').addClass('test');
```

What is the fastest way to add a "test" class to the element? Also, how could you know which one?

Comment: You can test this yourself: http://jsperf.com

Comment: Wow! The website I wanted, thanks Rory!

Comment: It looks like someone already wrote a similar test: https://jsperf.com/find-vs-find-and-filter/4. If you require you can amend it to work from a base selector.